# Bigquery invalid timestamp error when appending data from one table to another

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to copy data from one table to another having different partition and clustering fields, but I keep getting invalid timestamp error. Data into my source table was always written using standardSQL and I don't run in issue querying data from the source table. Did anyone else run into similar issue?

This is how my tables looks like:

```
Project: sample
Dataset: test
Table Name: table_a
event_id integer,
event_name string,
event_category string,
service_name string
service_timestamp timestamp
event_timestamp timestamp
Partitioned by event_timestamp, Clustered By: event_category

Project: sample
Dataset: test
Table Name: table_b
event_id integer,
event_name string,
event_category string,
service_name string
service_timestamp timestamp
event_timestamp timestamp
Partitioned by event_timestamp, Clustered By: service_name
```

I am trying to copy data from table_a to table_b using following command:

```
bq query --allow_large_results --append_table --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table 'sample.test.table_b'  "select * from \`sample.test.table_a\` where event_timestamp>='2018-01-01'";
```

````
Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 632691030736614000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field service_timestamp```
````

Comment: This means you have a corrupted date value in either `event_timestamp` or in `service_timestamp`. Can you do a `SELECT` from `table_a` using these fields and show this is possible